# Firestore addOnCompleteListener() not working in android application

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm encountering a problem with the `addOnCompleteListener()` function that needed to be used
in order to retrieve data from Cloud Firestore to my android application (developed in android studio).

This is a simple code I'm using in order to do so:

```
        FirebaseFirestore mDatabase;
        mDatabase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mDatabase.collection("SavedGames")
                .document("game1")
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                        if (document.exists()) {
                           Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                        } else {
                           Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                    }
                });
```

I've literally took this code from the official firebase site.
When debugging, each time I'm getting to `get().addOnCompleteListener(...)`, the cursor exits all.
I've tried to uninstall my app, change my authorizations rules, checked that I have google-service.json,
cleaned my android project, updating gradles but nothing fixed this issue.

this is my build.gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

any suggestions of what can cause that?

Comment: "the cursor exits all" - exits the application? Is there a stacktrace, or logging?

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint on `if (task.isSuccessful()) {` and run the app? Does it reach that breakpoint? If so, is the task successful or not? If not, what is `task.getException()`?

Comment: Is your onComplete method even triggered?

Comment: sorry, i wasn't really understandable - by saying 'the cursor exits all', i mean it just exit the current function and goes to another one, just skipping the addOnCompleteListener() and not entering. regrading task.isSuccessful() - I'm not even arriving to this function. it just exit when arriving to addOnCompleteListener(). I put this function inside a function called CodePage() that triggered when the user press a button (the layout hold android:onClick field), so maybe that is the issue? when pressing a button, this function supposed to be triggered and after -enter to another activity.

Comment: `addOnCompleteListener` accepts an asynchronous callback class as a parameter argument, you have created an anonymous class in your example that will be called asynchronously

Comment: the requested data exists? Do you have documents on that collection?

Comment: yes, collection and documents exists.
but if they were not - it still needs to enter addOnCompleteListener(), isn't it?